# How to get update statement in trigger function or when condition

Tags: postgresql, triggers

```
CREATE TABLE accounts (
 id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
 email TEXT,
 verified BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
 ...
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_reset_verified() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN 
IF (
    OLD.email != NEW.email -- do nothing if no change
) THEN
    RAISE NOTICE 'UPDATE';
    UPDATE users SET verified=FALSE WHERE id=NEW.id;
END IF;
RETURN NEW;
END; $$ language 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER reset_verified AFTER UPDATE OF email ON accounts
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (OLD.email != NEW.email) -- only when email changed
EXECUTE PROCEDURE fn_reset_verified();
```

Based on above schema, I wish to create trigger to automatic update verified to false if user change email. 
It work well for below statement:

```
UPDATE accounts SET email='newemail@email.com' WHERE id=1;
```

My problem come in when I intend update the email and set verified to TRUE at same time like below statement:

```
UPDATE accounts SET email='verified@email.com', verified=TRUE WHERE id=1;
```

If verified is been set in update statement, I should skip the function. Maybe condition as below:

```
WHEN (OLD.email != NEW.email AND STATEMENT.verified IS NULL)
```

So is there any way I can get the update statement or involved column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should NEVER call `UPDATE` on a table within an update trigger on that table. Chances are that you will endless loop (not in this particular case, but anyway) and there are typically better ways to achieve the same thing.

In your case, you would make a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger that fires when the email address changes and check/modify the `verified` column within that trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_reset_verified() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN 
    -- Below condition does not have to be checked because of WHEN clause in trigger
IF (
    OLD.email != NEW.email -- do nothing if no change
) THEN
    RAISE NOTICE 'UPDATE';
    NEW.verified := ...;
END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END; $$ language 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER reset_verified BEFORE UPDATE OF email ON accounts
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (OLD.email != NEW.email) -- only when email changed
EXECUTE PROCEDURE fn_reset_verified();
```

However, there is no logic to determine what to set `NEW.verified` to inside the trigger. The thing is, the `NEW` variable holds the values of all the columns of the new row *after* setting the columns with new values, not just those values being modified by the command. So if `NEW.verified = true` there is no way to know if the command that invoked the trigger was:

```
UPDATE accounts SET email = 'newemail@email.com', verified = true WHERE id = 1;
```

or

```
UPDATE accounts SET email = 'newemail@email.com' WHERE id = 1;
```

So `NEW.verified` could refer to the old email address or to the new email address which is specifically labeled as verified in the `UPDATE` command.

Your only option is to change your logic: if the email address changes, it always needs to be verified after, so `NEW.verified = false`.

Comment: Thanks for your highlight for use 'NEW.verified := ' instead of call update again. The reason I need to fire fn_reset_verified only if verified is not in the sql statement is because some admin user is allow to skip email verification. I can think of other work around to make it work. 
Create this question is because I am new to pgsql (previously use mysql), therefore I want to confirm whether object like 'Statement' do exists in pgsql. 
Anyway thanks for your answer.